# How to break for-each in XSLT and how to update existing variable in XSLT

Tags: php, xslt

Once the value is added for variable isSetHybridVlanValue I want to break loop. below is my part of code where I want to do changes

```
<xsl:variable name="isSetHybridVlanValue" select="0"></xsl:variable> **---I have created this flag variable---**
<xsl:variable name="hybridVlanValue">
    <xsl:for-each select="$vTokens">
        <xsl:if test="$isSetHybridVlanValue = 0"> **---Checking this variable if it is 0 then continue---**
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(current(), 'H')">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="normalize-space(substring-after(current(), 'H'))" />
                    <!-- <xsl:variable name="isSethybridVlanValue">
                        <xsl:value-of select="1" />
                    </xsl:variable> -->
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:if
                        test="contains($isHybridVlanInPortal, 'true') and count($vTokens) = 2 and $voipEnabledVlan != current()">
                        <xsl:value-of select="current()" />**---Once it is set I want to break this loop hence below I am trying to change existing variable to 1---**
                        <xsl:variable name="isSetHybridVlanValue" select = "1"/>**---It's showing error here, I want to change value of this existing variable isSetHybridVlanValue---**
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Here I want to update flag variable but it is not working. Please give me suggestion to update existing variable or any other solution so that I can break for each once it is set value for variable hybridVlanValue

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use XSLT as if it were a procedural language rather than a functional language. You need to do some background reading: See for example [Loop over a set of elements in xsl with a temporary value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586781/loop-over-a-set-of-elements-in-xsl-with-a-temporary-value).

It's difficult to reverse-engineer your requirements from code that not only doesn't work, but is written with completely wrong assumptions about the nature of the language. It would be better to start again by saying what you are trying to achieve: give your input and your desired output and make it clear how they relate to each other.